# Спецсимволы http запроса

Tags: html, c++, qt, http, post

Допустим обрабатываю форму post-методом. При http-запросе я получаю, например, вместо переноса на новую строку %0D%0A, а вместо пробела символ '+'. Я прекрасно понимаю зачем это придумали, но как мне привести эти данные в начальное положение? Вручную каждый символ пихать в метод replace не хочется. Может быть есть готовое решение? Я делаю веб-сервер на `С++` с помощью фреймворка `Qt`, если что

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html чем не устраивает?

Comment: Какой метод нужен? Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

`QUrl::fromEncoded(<str>.toLocal8Bit()).path()` - возвращает декодированную строку